# test a boolean expression in a Python string

Tags: python, parsing

I have a boolean expression in a string. eg. `20 < 30`. Is there a simple way to parse and evaluate this string so it will return `True` (in this case).

`ast.literal_eval("20 < 30")` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> eval("20<30")
True
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this a user-defined string, or one you're defining?

If it's a string you're creating, you could use `eval` (`eval("20 < 30")`), but if the string is given by the user, you might want to sanitize it first...

Comment: I create it. No worries :) Eval is indeed a very nice and very BIG security hole.

Answer (score 0):

`ast.literal_eval` shouldn't work since (from the docs) "The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.". The expression `20<30` requires some kind of evaluation, before it *returns* a `bool`.

A safer suggestion would be to split the string on the operator and `literal_eval` each side before passing to `eval`, ie.

```
import ast

expr = "20 < 30"
operator = "<"
lhs,rhs = map(ast.literal_eval, map(str.strip, expr.split(operator)))
eval("%s %s %s"%(lhs,operator,rhs))
```

Wrapping the thing in a `try, except` clause will catch some input errors when evaluating `lhs,rhs`.