# Apply comparison operator from string

Tags: python, comparison

I have a class `Foo` which contains one of math comparison operations `op` as a string: '<', '>' or '='. Also `Foo` contains a number `val`.

```py
class Foo:
  def __init__(self, operation: str, value: int):
    self.op = operation
    self.val = value
```

In my code I read a number from input and compare it to `Foo`'s class exemplar value using `Foo`'s contained operation:

```py
f = Foo('<', 15)
to_check = int(input())

if f.op == '<':
  if to_check < f.val:
    # ...
elif f.op == '>':
  if to_check > f.val:
    # ...
elif f.op == '=':
  if to_check == f.val:
    #...
```

Is there any way to do it simpler or more elegant?

Comment: You might be able to use ast.literal_eval to evaluate it as a string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more elegant and works just fine :

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self, op: str, val: int):
        self.op = op
        self.val = val

    def check(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            if self.op == '<': return self.val > other
            if self.op == '>': return self.val < other
            if self.op == '=': return self.val == other
            if self.op == '!=': return self.val != other
            if self.op == '>=': return self.val <= other
            if self.op == '<=': return self.val >= other
        return NotImplemented
```

`f.check(other)` check the condition of the contained operation and returns it, in other words:

```
f = Foo('<', 15)
if f.check(14):
    print('ok')
```

The condition is `True` because `14` is less than `15`

Comment: There is sometimes an aversion to multiple return statements (though no consensus: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31992052/python-coding-style-multiple-return-statements). However this gets extra points for readability.

Comment: 1. `if isinstance(other, int) or isinstance(other, float):` can be reduced to `if isinstance(other, (int, float)):` - will against each type given. 2. If `val` is not an int or float, don't return `False`, it should [`return NotImplemented`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#NotImplemented).

Comment: Tanks for letting me know ! I didn't know that `NotImplemented` was a thing. I fixed it

Answer (score 3):

**An alternative:** If I were using the Foo class in a program, I think I would use @S-c-r-a-t-c-h-y's approach. But here is a perhaps elegant approach using the functional form of comparison operators.

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, operation: str, value: int):
        self.op = operation
        self.val = value

f = Foo('<', 15)
to_check = int(12)

import operator
op_dict = {
    '>': operator.gt,
    '<': operator.lt,
    '==':operator.eq
}

op_dict.get(f.op)(to_check, f.val)
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for answering, but I also considered to store operation not like a string, but a lambda. It seems to be not a bad solution for my case:

```py
less = lambda x, y: x < y
equal = lambda x, y: x == y

f = Foo(less, 15)
to_check = 12

if f.op(to_check, f.val):
  #...
```

Comment: This is a good approach also. You could make it simpler by using `operator.gt` and `operator.eq` instead of making them with lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

This will work with `eval`. But caution must be used with `eval`! See this post for a safer way by first parsing with `ast.literal_eval`.
[test a boolean expression in a Python string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586778/test-a-boolean-expression-in-a-python-string)

The safer approach might not count any longer as "simpler" or "more elegant".

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, operation: str, value: int):
        self.op = operation
        self.val = value

f = Foo('<', 15)
to_check = int(input())

eval(f'{to_check} {f.op} {f.val}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Python has built in to do that. We can override them

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, operation: str, value: int):
        self.op = operation
        self.value = value
    def __repr__(self):
        
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({self.value} {self.op} input_X )"

    def __lt__(self, input_value):
        return self.value < input_value

    def __le__(self, input_value):
        return self.value <= input_value
    
    def __eq__(self, input_value):
        return self.value == input_value
    
    def __gt__(self, input_value):
        return self.value > input_value
    
    def __ge__(self, input_value):
        return self.value >= input_value
    
    def check(self, input_value:int):
        
        operations = {'<': self.__lt__,
                     '<=': self.__le__,
                     '==': self.__eq__,
                     '>': self.__gt__,
                     '>=':self.__ge__}
        
        return operations.get(self.op)( input_value)
```

### demo

```py
f = Foo(">=", 15)
print(f)
# Foo(15 >= input_X )

f.check(14)
# True
f.check(16)
# False

f > 16 
# False

f > 14
# True
```

Comment: Clever approach. Though I think this is a little bit of a mangling of the builtins like `__lt__`. Those would be more appropriate if we were comparing different `Foo` instantiations like `f1 = Foo(); f2 = Foo(); f1 > f2`.  In this case I would just make those private functions like `def _less_than` or use the `operators.lt`.

Comment: Now, I fixed ;) but it is a hack still